# Linking a shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

Trying to link a shared library throws an undefined reference in `main`. The exact error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3pGAwi.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `sum'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here are my files:

*build.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

PROJECT_NAME="foo"
CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -pedantic"

gcc $CFLAGS -shared -fPIC -o libsubmodule.so submodule.c
gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROJECT_NAME -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -lsubmodule main.c
```

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "submodule.h"
int main(void)
{
  printf("%s", "Help Me!!!\n");
  printf("%i\n",sum(2, 3));
  return 0;
}
```

*submodule.h*

```
#ifndef SUBMODULE_H_
#define SUBMODULE_H_
int sum(int a, int b);
#endif // SUBMODULE_H_
```

*submodule.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "submodule.h"
int sum(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

I would expect this program to compile and print

```
Help me!!!
5
```

when run.

If I directly compile *submodule.c* into my executable, the program behaves as expected.

I think my libsubmodule.so is working fine because `nm libsubmodule.so` has the line

```
00000000000010f9 T sum
```

I think my code should work because I am `#include`ing the header file, using `-L.` and `-Wl,-rpath=.` to tell the linker where to find the library, and I am linking it into my executable using `-lsubmodule`.

I'm pretty sure I'm finding the library correctly because it would throw a different error. I also think I'm finding the header correctly. I don't understand how the library can contain `sum`, be linked into the executable successfully, and then have its functions not be found. EDIT: I believe the library is found by the linker, but then it cant be linked into the program.

Comment: What is the output of `ldd foo`? This will show you which libraries the executable is linked against, so `libsubmodule.so` should be in there.

Comment: Unfortunately @MichaelM. I don't have a "foo" file because the compilation is failing before the executable get built

Comment: Change the order of argumengs at linkage: `gcc ... main.c -lsubmodule`

Comment: Yes I recently figured that out. The linker resolves dependencies from left to right so be sure to put your libraries after the classes that use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROJECT_NAME -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -lsubmodule main.c
```

when you specify library to be linked the linker has no missing reference to `sum`, as it is done in `main.o`, so it will not include the module `libsubmodule.so` in the executable (you specified it as a library, not as a module)  Just write those parameters in the reverses order.

```
gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROJECT_NAME -L. -Wl,-rpath=. main.c -lsubmodule
```

and the link will go fine.

Probably you will have trouble to find a shared executable in your current directory, and you will need also to add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` before executing your program (the shared libraries should be in a registered directory, see `ldconfig(8)`)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

PROJECT_NAME="foo"
CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -pedantic"

gcc $CFLAGS -shared -fPIC -o libsubmodule.so submodule.c main.c
gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROJECT_NAME -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -lsubmodule main.c
```

run below command:

```
bash build.sh
./foo
```

You will get file `foo` and `libsubmodule.so` and get output:

```
Help Me!!!
5
```

Below is picture:

[image]

Comment: What did you change about the build porcess?

Comment: After adding main.c into the shared library (which defeats the point of a shared library?) it throws a different error.
./foo: error while loading shared libraries: libsubmodule.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
and ldd says libsubmodule.so is not found

Comment: @MichaelM. The origin problem is "I would expect this program to compile and print"

Comment: Sorry disregard my response. The program does compile and print, but that is unsatisfactory because I can't use it a like a shared library if I need to compile main into it. To be clear @Tom has a working solution and ldd foo shows the library being linked. However, I dont get why this worked, and It is unsatisfactory to have to compile every program that uses a shared library into the shared library

Comment: @lonk Does I misunderstand you problem?

Comment: Either that or I misunderstand the whole situation. My idea of a shared library is that its a piece of compiled code that can be linked into any other executable. If I want to use my sum function in several different executables, with your solution I believe I would have to compile each main.c from each project into the shared library. That is not how I understand shared libraries to work.

Comment: this is what I am trying to emulate
    clang $CFLAGS -o ./build/libplug.so -fPIC -shared ./src/plug.c ./src/ffmpeg_linux.c $LIBS
    clang $CFLAGS -DHOTRELOAD -o ./build/musializer ./src/musializer.c $LIBS -L./build/ -Wl,-rpath=./build/ -Wl,-rpath=./
This is probably like off topic or whatever but I understand it to be the same idea as what I am doing
for reference: https://github.com/tsoding/musializer/blob/master/build.sh

Comment: @lonk  Just like .dll file in Windows system?

Comment: @Tom is a .so not the same as a .dll? I am on linux by the way. I am not familiar with windows so I am not sure.

Comment: I believe that in order to get the behavior I am describing I must use dlopen and dlsym in the source code in order to find the reference to "sum". I cant try this now but if that works I will mark this as solved and credit you for the solution. Sorry for saying you solved it in a way that wouldnt work for me. In reality, I am just leaning this stuff and so simply didnt understand the fundamentals. Cheers @Tom

Answer (score 0):

Alright here we go. First thanks to @Tom for showing me how far off my understanding was. Here is the solution I was looking for. Basically, my issue was that I linked libsubmodule.so against my executable, but I didn't load the library into memory or read through its contents. The "undefined reference to sum" was because I needed to manually open and search through the library and get a pointer to that location in memory. The solution revolves around dlopen() and dlsym(), both of which have very good man pages. Below are the new build.sh and main.c.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

PROJECT_NAME="funky_pointers"
CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra"
LIBS="-ldl" // Gotta link the libdl system library

gcc $CFLAGS -shared -fPIC -o libsubmodule.so submodule.c // don't need to put main.c in the .so like @Tom suggested
gcc $CFLAGS -o $PROJECT_NAME -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -lsubmodule $LIBS main.c
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "submodule.h"

int main(void)
{
  printf("%s", "Watch this!\n");

  const char *submodule_name = "libsubmodule.so";
  void *submodule = dlopen(submodule_name, RTLD_NOW); // get a handle to the .so
  if (submodule == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load %s\n", submodule_name);
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Loading success!\n");
  int (*sum)(int, int) = dlsym(submodule, "sum"); // get a pointer to the sum function

  int out = sum(2, 3); // profit
  printf("%i\n", out);
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this is helpful to my fellow 0x developers. Keep it up!